# Using javascript classes in Windows Store Apps

Tags: javascript, windows-store-apps, winjs

I have the following class definition:

```
var gameEngine = WinJS.Namespace.define("GameEngine", {    

interaction: WinJS.Class.define(
    function() {},
    {
        destination: 0,
        currentXPos: 0,
        handleTouch: function handleTouch(event) {
            this.destination = event.x;
            console.log("New destination: " + this.destination);
        }
    }
),
...
```

And I'm trying to use the `handleTouch` function here:

```
WinJS.Namespace.define("drawScreen", {

DrawScreen: WinJS.Class.define(function DrawScreen() {
    canvas.addEventListener("MSPointerUp", gameEngine.interaction.handleTouch, false);

...
```

The problem seems to be that `gameEngine.interaction.handleTouch` is undefined.  Clearly I've not declared or called the `interaction` class correctly - but looking at documentation [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/apps/br229813.aspx), I can't see what I've done wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you've defined `gameEngine.interaction` as a class with your members in the instance declaration, you need to instantiate an instance of it first. Therefore you'd need to do something like this:

```
var gameInteraction = new gameEngine.interaction();
canvas.addEventListener("MSPointerUp", gameInteraction.handleTouch, false);
```

If you define all of the `interaction` class members directly inside of the Namespace instead of in a Class, you wouldn't need to instantiate it. Another alternative would be to instantiate the class directly in your namespace like:

```
var gameEngine = WinJS.Namespace.define("GameEngine", {    

interaction: new WinJS.Class.define(
...
```

Comment: Your second suggestion doesn't make any difference - it still sees the constituent function as undefined.  The first works fine though - thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The first argument to `WinJS.Class.define(` is the constructor function, while the second is the member properties and functions. Try this:

```
interaction: WinJS.Class.define(
    function() {},
    {
        // initialize your class here
    }, 
    {
        destination: 0,
        currentXPos: 0,
        handleTouch: function handleTouch(event) {
            this.destination = event.x;
            console.log("New destination: " + this.destination);
        }
    }
),
...
```

Comment: To clarify what you've done here is to shift the variables down from the instance members declaration into the static members declaration for the class. This should also be a viable alternative to the two other suggestions I posted.